# Python: Using pdb with Flask application

Tags: python, flask, pdb

I'm using Flask 0.9 with Python 2.7.1 within a virtualenv, and starting my app with `foreman start`

In other apps I've built when I add the following line to my app:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

then reload the browser window, my terminal window displays the pdb interactive debugger:

```
(pdb)
```

However in my app when I add those lines nothing happens. The browser window hangs and shows a constant state of loading yet nothing shows in the console.

Is there some magic that needs to happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you're using Foreman, which captures the standard output.

To debug your app with `pdb`, you'll need to "manually" run it, using `python app.py` or whatever you use.

Alternatively, you can use [WinPDB](http://winpdb.org/) (which, despite the name, has *nothing* to do with the operating system), which will let you remotely debug a Python process. You can even use it when the program is running on another server.

Comment: Ahhh. I had no clue. Thanks for that tidbit David.